# Is there a way to retrieve the transformation state in CSS animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, animation

Say I have a PNG that is translated horizontally using CSS:

```
.example_scroller_png {
  background-image: url('http://example.com/example.png'); 
}

.example_scroller {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: repeat-x; 
  background-position: right bottom;
  -webkit-animation: slide 30s linear infinite;
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  from { background-position: left bottom; }
    to { background-position: right bottom; }
}
```

I have a simple `div` to contain the PNG (using `className` instead of `class` to denote use of ReactJS):

```
<div className="example_scroller example_scroller_png" />
```

Is there a way to programmatically retrieve the current horizontal pixel offset value of the PNG as rendered within the `div`?

Failing that, I am using ReactJS. Is there a React library that enables the same family of animations, and which also provides the translation/scale etc. parameters within an animated component's state?

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#transition-events  keep the animation out of user-land if at all possible

Comment: have you tried react motion? https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion